# Can't display losing message if hangman wrong

Tags: java, image, if-statement

I've used an if statement to change the images of my hangman application and so far it works but when I want to display a message when error reaches 6, it somehow prints `You Lose` in every error.

```
if(wrong >= 1)
       icon = new ImageIcon("hangman1.jpg");
   if(wrong >= 2)
       icon = new ImageIcon("hangman2.jpg");
   if(wrong >= 3)
       icon = new ImageIcon("hangman3.jpg");
   if(wrong >= 4)
       icon = new ImageIcon("hangman4.jpg");
   if(wrong >= 5)
       icon = new ImageIcon("hangman5.jpg");
   if(wrong >= 6)
       icon = new ImageIcon("hangman6.jpg");
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Lose");
     label.setIcon(icon);
```

Comment: `"You Loose"`  The word you mean only has one 'o' - 'Lose'.

Comment: This question is hardly too localized, it is a straight forward general programming question. Granted a simple one.

Comment: Try dry running your code when `wrong = 2`. What happens? Every `if` condition starting `if(wrong >= 2)` is `true`. Do you want that? Change all the conditions to use `switch case`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need brackets around your code in that condition, otherwise only the first line is part of the conditional.

Also, your conditionals all get executed when wrong > 1. Use == and/or the else/if construct.

```
if (wrong == 1) {
    ...
} 
else if (wrong == 2) {
    ...
}
...
else if(wrong >= 6) 
{
       icon = new ImageIcon("hangman6.jpg");
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Loose");
}
```

Comment: But then my image all appear at once but only when error counter reaches 6

Comment: You should change the conditions in the first five to plain ==, otherwise its executing every block.

Comment: Still only changes the image when error counter reaches 6

Comment: I think that is outside the scope of what you have posted here.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are not using braces `{ }` around the code that is run in each if statement. Without braces, only the line after each if statement is run.

```
//icon is always hangman plus the number wrong
icon = new ImageIcon("hangman" + wrong + ".jpg");


// only show the message dialog after 6 wrong guesses
if(wrong >= 6){
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Lose!");
}

label.setIcon(icon);
```

Answer (score 0):

You already got the answer to your question, missing `{}`. But read on `switch case`

Try this:

```
switch(wrong) {
case 1: icon = new ImageIcon("hangman1.jpg");
        break;
case 2: icon = new ImageIcon("hangman2.jpg");
        break;
//and so on...
case 6: icon = new ImageIcon("hangman6.jpg");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Loose");
        break;
}
```

You shouldn't use too many `else if`. It will make the code less readable.

Answer (score 0):

So figured out why and its because my labels didn't know that its been updated by a new image, thanks to the curly brackets idea

```
if(wrong == 1){
       icon = new ImageIcon("hangman1.jpg");
       label.setIcon(icon);
                 }
                 else if(wrong == 2)
                 {
       icon = new ImageIcon("hangman2.jpg");
       label.setIcon(icon);
                 }
                 else if(wrong == 3)
                 {
       icon = new ImageIcon("hangman3.jpg");
       label.setIcon(icon);
                 }
                else if(wrong == 4){
       icon = new ImageIcon("hangman4.jpg");
       label.setIcon(icon);
                 }
                else if(wrong == 5){
       icon = new ImageIcon("hangman5.jpg");
       label.setIcon(icon);
                 }
                else if(wrong == 6){
       icon = new ImageIcon("hangman6.jpg");
       label.setIcon(icon);
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Lose");   
                 }
```

Comment: You don't need to use `label.setIcon(icon);` after every single `if condition`. Just add it once after the last condition.